# WCF Rest Service.. Convert Datatable to XML

Tags: .net, xml, rest, wcf

I have a WCF rest service I am building that can return XML and Json. It works but when I make a call to return XML my XML is a string not XML. I think this is because I am converting a datatable to XML.

The WCF provides the Response in proper XML so I am not sure how to put Datatable XML/text in the WCF XML Response and have it be actual XML.

Here is my code... I can provide more if needed..
I believe I am going about this correct but am missing something.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

IRest.vb

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,      
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate:="xml/getassetnames/?key={key}")>
Function GetAssetNamesXML(key As String) As String
```

Function to convert datatable to XML

```
  Public Shared Function ToXml(dt As DataTable) As String
    Using textWriter = New StringWriter()
        Dim settings = New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True
        settings.IndentChars = "    "
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

        Using xmlWriter__1 = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings)
            dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter__1)
            Return textWriter.ToString()

        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Implements GetAssetNames IRest  .. my .svc

```
Public Function GetAssetNamesXML(ByVal Key As String) As String Implements   IAquaViewRest.GetAssetNamesXML

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = GetAssetNamesDT(Key) 'runs a function that goes to the database and returns a DT
    Return ToXml(dt)
    dt.Clear()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any responses but wanted to post my solution so others can hopefully use it.

The main issue is that using a string for the function in the operation contract and converting a DT to XML then having the response set to XML double serializes it. Not sure if I am using the correct terminology but basically it encapsulates your DT with a string tag and that's that.

So the way around this is to have your operation contract as System.IO.Stream. This also means you will need a better convert DT to XML function..

Here is the final code...

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           UriTemplate:="xml/getassetnames/?key={key}")>
Function GetAssetNamesXML(key As String) As System.IO.Stream
```

DT to XML

```
Public Shared Function ToXml(dt As DataTable) As String

    Dim settings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    settings.IndentChars = "    "

    Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, settings)

    Using xmlWriter__1 = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, settings)
        dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter__1)
        Dim xml As String = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(memStream.ToArray())
        Return xml

    End Using

End Function
```

svc.vb

```
Public Function GetAssetNamesXML(ByVal Key As String) As System.IO.Stream Implements IAquaViewRest.GetAssetNamesXML

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = GetAssetNamesDT(Key)
    Dim TempStr As String = ToXml(dt)
    Dim resultBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TempStr)

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain"

    Return New MemoryStream(resultBytes)
    dt.Clear()

End Function
```